# how to create a custom ratingbar

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ratingbar

I'm trying to create a custom RatingBar for one of my apps. I've followed this tutorial: http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

The problem is that my RatingBar has always the same size and it's always filled. I try to show different ratings (0,1,2,3,4...) but the rating bar it's the same in all the cases...

I have the ratingBar:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/MyRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
```

My Style:

```
<style name="MyRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_list</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">57dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">57dip</item>
</style>
```

The layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@color/white_text" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
      android:drawable="@color/white_text" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
      android:drawable="@color/red_circle" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<RatingBar>` use:
`android:numStars` to define how many `red_circle` are used for the full scale of the bar.
`android:rating` to set the default rating level.
`android:stepSize` to define the step size of your RatingBar.

**`<Edit>`**
I don't believe RatingBar is designed to work using a straight fill color as the progress drawable, which is what you have currently. A color has no dimensions, so drawing 2, 3 or 4 of them has no meaning.
It is designed to work with an image file like the default star png files.

Change your layer-list so the progress drawable points to a Bitmap, or 9Patch, and it works fine. `<RatingBar>` extends ProgressBar, which uses 9Patchs for the progress drawable.

Comment: I assume that it's not possible to use colors to fill a ratingbar.

Comment: You could make a 9Patch Drawable square of the desired solid color, and use that.

Comment: Thanks Sound conception, I've found something similar in another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295088/shapedrawable-as-progressdrawable-for-ratingbar-in-android