# Android rating bar set star dimension

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am displaying rating bar in my application where i want to reduce the dimensions of the star.
so here is xml of rating bar

```
       <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:max="5"
                android:stepSize="0.25"
                android:numStars="0"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:isIndicator="true"/>
```

i am setting color and setting rating like this

```
 private RatingBar ratingBar;
 Drawable ratingBarColor = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
 Drawable ratingBarColor = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
ratingBar.setRating((float) (value));
 DrawableCompat.setTint(ratingBarColor, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.red));
```

But the problem is regardless of any value the color and decimal filling won't work.I am using style to reduce star dimensions.strange is if i remove **style** attribute in xml it will set exact value as star but dimension will reset to default.if i add min/max height to star the image will get cropped.
here is the same problem :- [How to set the custom size of the stars in RatingBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382632/how-to-set-the-custom-size-of-the-stars-in-ratingbar)
tried :`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"` still same issue.
i am not getting what's wrong with the style attribute.

Comment: reduce star image size

Comment: Color is not filling based on the value. if i reduce the dimension the image is getting cropped. please see linked question.

Comment: maxsize and minsize are equal to star image size than image are not cropped

Comment: Then where is image dimension get reduced?

Comment: <RatingBar
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1.0"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/userratingbar">

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be useful anymore, but I made a custom library which allows you to change star dimension programatically (among other stuff): [SimpleRatingBar](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).

It features:

- Fully working `android:layout_width`: it can be set to `wrap_content`, `match_parent` or abritary dp.
- Arbitrary number of stars.
- Arbitrary step size.
- Size of stars can be controlled exactly or by setting a maximum size.
- Customizable colors in normal state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable colors in pressed state (border, fill and background of stars and rating bar).
- Customizable size separation between stars.
- Customizable border width of stars.
- Customizable stars corner radius.
- Allows to set OnRatingBarChangeListener
- Stars fill can be set to start from left to right or from right to left (RTL language support).
- AnimationBuilder integrated in the view to set rating programatically with animation.

[Here is a preview of it](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar/raw/master/images/sample.gif).

In your case, you would just have to do:

```
ratingbar.setStarSize(20, Dimension.DP);
```

or, for example, in pixels:

```
ratingbar.setStarSize(100, Dimension.PX);
```

You can find it either in `jcenter` or in `Maven Central`. So in your `build.gradle` file just add to your dependencies:

`compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.+'`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Let me try it.